# Primefaces datatable sorting after filtering

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I have a p:dataTable which stores the results of a processed form, and I perform the following actions:

1. Fill form values.
2. Submit.
3. Data table is populated -- filter on any column.
4. Change form values.
5. Submit.
6. Data table is populated with new results.
7. Sort on any column -- filtered results from #3 are displayed.

I have an arraylist for the filtered values, but I am not doing anything to it in the bean. On submit, I am calling an actionListener which casts the dataTable to primefaces.components.datatable.DataTable and then calling a resetValue() on it (see code snippet below), before I process the form.

I've tried multiple ways of resetting, clearing and updating the dataTable, but I'm not able to get around the above issue. Just for reference, this is my p:dataTable tag:

```
<p:dataTable
            id="resultsDataTable"
            rendered="#{entityReportBean.isResultsPopulated}"
            var="change"
            value="#{entityReportBean.entityChangeDto}"
            styleClass="resultsPanel"
            rows="100"
            paginator="true"
            paginatorPosition="top"
            paginatorTemplate="#{PreviousPageLink}  Previous  {CurrentPageReport}  Next  {NextPageLink}"
            filterEvent="enter"
            filteredValue="#{entityReportBean.filteredResults}" >
```

and this is the actionListener:

```
    public void onSubmit() {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            DataTable resultsTable = (DataTable) context.getViewRoot().findComponent("results:resultsDataTable");
            resultsTable.resetValue();
                ...
```

I am fairly new to JSF/Primefaces so there might be some basic operation I'm unaware of. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I realized that there was no point trying to do anything in my actionListener as that is not being invoked on sort. So I added an ajax 'sort' event on the dataTable and added a `resultsTable.updateValue(entityChangeDto);` to the listener. Now all is well.